# Facebook App extended permissions

Tags: facebook, permissions, fbml

I am making a FBML facebook application. Currently, when a user visit my application for the first time he is asked to allow his profile details to be shared or not. I want the user to be asked for publish_stream permissions in the same login screen. How can I do this?

As far as i know the way to do is redirect the user to a url like:

```
<fb:if-is-app-user>
<!-- your normal code -->
<fb:else>
<fb:redirect url="http://www.facebook.com/login.php?v=1.0&api_key=[your_app_key]&next=[your_canvas_page_URL]&canvas="/>
</fb:else>
</fb:if-is-app-user>
```

I guess my URL is wrong because of the fact there is no place to insert the comma seperated list of permissions that I require!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual link where the user should be redirected is following:

```
<fb:redirect url="http://www.facebook.com/login.php?v=1.0&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&next=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fxxxxxxxxxxx%2F&canvas=&req_perms=publish_stream"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen, Facebook changed their policy to ask for extended permission during authentication. Visit [this link](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/apply-new-data-model-and-do-specific-change/) to learn more.

Comment: Please stop using bit.ly or tinyurl ! This isnt Twitter, you have enough space here and I like to see where the link is going!